# Why can't I map array to Material UI Chip?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am using Next.js and I want to map some array of element to Material-UI chip, but after compiling I got this error:

`Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const chipList = [
    { key: "1", label: "Hello" },
    { key: "2", label: "Elyas" }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {chipList.map((data, index) => (
          <Chip key={data.key + index} label={data.label} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-browser-9de2n

This is my first question on Stack Overflow. Any help would be appreciated so much! Thank you!

Comment: its ```import { Chip } from "@material-ui/core";``` you just need to put the braces I think `{ }`

Comment: your codesandbox link is weird it does not have any HTML page like `index.html`

Comment: @monesulhaque idk i just used codesandbox next.js template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the curly braces around the Chip import

```
import { Chip } from "@material-ui/core";
```

Comment: ah, my stupidity hits me so hard. thank you for answering!